# React Native: Error message when running react-native run-ios

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native

Has anyone run into this issue?

I've used both solutions but no luck...

**Solution 1: iOS**
Delete the build folder and rerun the project
rm -rf ios/build 
react-native run-ios

**Solution 2: iOS**
Open a second terminal window in the project directory and run npm start. Then in the first terminal window, run react-native run-ios.

I've provided a screenshot as well. I've also checked outside resources
(Google, Stack Overflow etc...)

Thank you in advance.

[image]

Comment: [Please don't post your code/errors as an image](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551). It's hard to read, prevents text-based searching, and lowers the overall presentation value of the post.

Answer (score 0):

After squinting with all my might...

Your JSX is

`<Text>Some Text<Text>`

That's two opening tags.  Instead, you need to use a closing tag to end the text element:

`<Text>Some Text</Text>`